# Loading and using Swiper 4.4.6 in Laravel 5.7 / Bootstrap 4.3

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

I am trying to find the best way to use Swiper in bootstrap 4 based on a Laravel 5.7 website.

In installed Swiper with `npm install swiper`.

**In app.js I have:**

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('swiper');
require('./custom');
```

bootstrap and custom are in resources/js just as app.js. Swiper is installed in /node_modules.

**In custom.js**

```
var ProjectSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,

    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
})
```

All above files are loaded and compiled correctly with `npm run watch`, no errors here.

Still, the swiper is not working while the browser console says 
`ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

```
window.Swiper = require('swiper').default;
```

This code will work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to load Swiper like this:

```
var Swiper = require('swiper');
```

or as an ES module:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

You could also decide to load it in boostrap.js, where the other libraries are loaded as well:

```
window.Swiper = require('swiper');
```

Comment: First two options same error: Swiper is not defined, the third options says: TypeError: Swiper is not a constructor (used as last line in bootstrap.js)